# Multiple else if Statements Fix

Tags: java

I have a random name generator using a simple Random system, basically it gets a number 1 - 10 then there are a bunch of is statements for the numbers

```
    if(f == 1)
    {
        fst = "Daws";
    }
    else if(f == 2)
    {
        fst = "Rom";
    }
    else if(f == 3)
    {
        fst = "Trout";
    }
    else if(f == 4)
    {
        fst = "Bally";
    }
    else if(f == 5)
    {
        fst = "Kuu";
    }
    else if(f == 6)
    {
        fst = "Invery";
    }
    else if(f == 7)
    {
        fst = "Dragon";
    }
    else if(f == 8)
    {
        fst = "Bam";
    }
    else if(f == 9)
    {
        fst = "Laen";
    }
    else if(f == 10)
    {
        fst = "Glen";
    }
```

is there a way I could condense this? any tips?

Comment: you could use a switch statement, but why dont you put your values in an array and get the item with the random index?

Comment: use switch. it's faster and more readable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a `switch` statement.

```
switch (f) {
case 1: fst = "Daws"; break;
case 2: fst = "Rom"; break;
...
}
```

Or, even better, create a lookup array:

```
String[] strs = { "Daws", "Rom", ... };
```

and use it as follows:

```
fst = strs[f-1];  // -1 since your random number starts from 1.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
// a condensed way of doing FSTS = { "Daws", "Rom", ... };
static final String[] FSTS = 
             "Daws,Rom,Trout,Bally,Kuu,Invery,Dragon,Bam,Laen,Glen".split(",");

// later
fst = FSTS[f-1];
```

Comment: also you taught me about the .split() which i was never aware of. for that I give you awesomeness++;